# Create label and text input when button is clicked in kivy python

Tags: python, responsive-design, kivy

while making a login screen in kivy. I want to create a signUp button which when clicked will add an extra TextInput box on the screen for password verification. Here is the code of main file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size=(600,600)

Builder.load_file('loginLayoutCSS.kv')

class loginLayout(Widget):
    def signIn(self):
        pass

    def signUp(self):
        pass

class Login(App):
    def build(Self):
        Window.clearcolor=(0,1,0.8,.1)
        return loginLayout()

if __name__=='__main__':
    Login().run()
```

Code for .kv file:

```
#:kivy 2.1.0
#:import utils kivy.utils
<TextInput>
    size_hint:(0.5,0.5)
    pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5}
    background_normal:''

<Label>
    font_size:32
    background_normal:''
    color:utils.get_color_from_hex('#0c4160')
    
<RoundedButton@Button>
    background_color:(0,0,0,0)
    background_normal:''
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba:(48/255,84/255,150/255,1)
        RoundedRectangle:
            size:self.size
            pos:self.pos
            radius:[45]
        
<loginLayout>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        size:root.width,root.height
        spacing:10
        padding:10

        Label:
            id:LabelHeading
            text:'Login'



        Label:
            text:'UserName'
            font_size:25
        TextInput:
            id:username
            multiline:False
            font_size:25

        Label:
            text:'Password'
            font_size:25
        TextInput:
            id:password
            multiline:False
            font_size:25
        TextInput:
            text:'Re-enter Password'
            font_size:25
            multiline:False
            id: reEnter            
        BoxLayout:
            orientation:'horizontal'
            spacing:20
            size_hint:(.7,0.5)
            pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5}
            RoundedButton:
                text:'Sign in'
                id:signIn
                color:utils.get_color_from_hex('#d9fcfa')
            RoundedButton:
                text:'Sign up'
                id:signUp
                color:utils.get_color_from_hex('#d9fcfa')
                on_press:root.signUp()
```

I want the TextInput with id=reEnter to be hidden until the signUp button is not clicked. If it is possible, please write the code for it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try with its prop. `height` ?

Comment: no, not yet.
Will the height do the trick in this?

Comment: Or you can set its `opacity` to `0` to make it disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should avoid naming dynamic class by their default name (do like`<MyTextInput@TextInput>` etc.).

To reveal `TextInput` only after a button is pressed, you can use its `height` property as follows:

Hide it first,

```py
        MyTextInput:
            text:'Re-enter Password'
            font_size:25
            multiline:False
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 0
            background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
            id: reEnter
```

Now pass the instance through button-press,

```py
            RoundedButton:
                text:'Sign up'
                id:signUp
                color:utils.get_color_from_hex('#d9fcfa')
                on_press:root.signUp(reEnter) # Pass the object.
```

Then in method `signUp`,

```py
    def signUp(self, obj):
        obj.size_hint_y = 0.0 # To avoid 'TypeError'.
        Animation(size_hint_y = 0.5, background_color = [1, 1, 1, 1], d = 0.5).start(obj)
```

Comment: You can make it visually pleasing by applying `Animation`, see the updated answer.